# How do you test/deploy an Angular 6+ webapp for Samsung TV with Tizen?

Tags: angular, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

I have to develop a webapp for a Samsung TV with Tizen and I was wondering if there was a way to use angular, but I can't find a way to make the Tizen emulator load the built version, the one out of the /dist folder.

When I try to emulate the webapp this is what it sends in the console
[image]